# Major Issue with Asus M4A78T-E Bios

Tags: bios

I am having major issues with my bios and I have tried three different forums in hopes that there is someone out there that can help me....

The issue is that every single time I turn off my computer, when I turn it back on the bios resets and tries to boot from a floppy drive....first problem is I dont have a floppy drive and secondly it does not read my HDD....

I tried everything to fix this...I tried replacing the cmos battery, I tried replacing the sata cable, and I tried a different sata port....none of these things seem to be working.

Now the messed up part about all of this is that i am on my computer right now....If I take the battery out and put it back in and setup the bios again manually I am able to get into my computer...but this is NOT normal...

Why is my bios resetting constantly when I power down my computer?

Please assist me I need my computer for business

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few possibilities:

1) Every CMOS battery you tried was dead or weak. (Did you try a brand new one?)

2) You are trying the wrong type of battery, your clear CMOS jumper is set to clear, or something is shorting against the motherboard.

3) Your CMOS is shot.

The first thing I'd check: Make sure your CLRTC jumper (right near the battery, between USB11/12 and USB9/10, not the one near the SATA ports) is jumped on pins 1 and 2. The jumper *must* be present.

Comment: I bought a brand new one 2 hours ago....If my cmos is shot would I still be able to get in here? I mean would my computer even boot up? Does that mean my Mobo is done or?

Comment: It depends how it is shot. If it's shot in that it has "sprung a leak", then yes, it will work fine when power is on. (That really happens. SRAM can fail such it draws excessive current, more than your computer can provide when it's off.) Check the CLRTC jumper.

Comment: The bios jumper is set to 1-2 and the CLRTC jumper is set to 2-3. It just does not make any sense at all...Why in the heck would I be able to get on my computer and have it run fine if something major was wrong....I mean if I had a short or something it would fry my computer and it would not even recognize my hdd...

Comment: Is there any way to fix this at all? I mean if it sprung a leak as you put it....?

Comment: If the CLRTC jumper is set to 2-3, that's your problem. The CLRTC jumper must be on 1-2.